# Android pie - disabled software back button breaks accessibility back action

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, android-9.0-pie

I've an app that can emulate the back button via the accessibility service by extending the `AccessibilityService` and using following:

```
performGlobalAction(AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK)
```

This works fine in all cases but one.

**Problem**

One of my users told me that it works on his android p device as long as his software buttons are enabled, but if he uses the new systems gesture navigation (like explained here: https://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-android-p-gesture-navigation-system) this action does not work anymore.

**Question**

Any ideas why or how I can solve this? Even detecting if gesture navigation is enabled or not would help a little...

Comment: Any solution? I am also want to know whether Navigation Gesture is enable or not?

Comment: No, sadly not...

Comment: Is there any method to check navigation bar is hidden or not? I tried with many solutions but not working.

Comment: In an activity and in a service with an overlay, you can detect it, otherwise I think not...

Comment: can you please guide me in that.. If possible using code then It will help in my case If I am able to find this.

Comment: what would be interesting for you? activity or service + overlay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189467/discussion-between-nik-and-prom85).

Comment: Hey did u guys find any solution?